# what's the difference between spark.yarn.secondary.jars and spark.yarn.dist.jars

Tags: apache-spark

As title. I couldn't find any useful doc for them.

chatgpt provided something confusing so I think stackoverflow is necessary here.

fomr gpt:

> The properties `spark.yarn.secondary.jars` and `spark.yarn.dist.jars` both relate to distributing additional JAR files to YARN worker nodes when running Apache Spark applications on a YARN cluster, but they serve slightly different purposes:
>
> 1. `spark.yarn.secondary.jars`: This property is used to specify additional JAR files that need to be distributed alongside the primary JAR file of your Spark application. These additional JAR files are typically dependencies required by your application, such as third-party libraries or other supporting files. They are considered secondary because they accompany the primary JAR file, which contains your application logic.
> 2. `spark.yarn.dist.jars`: This property, on the other hand, is used to specify a comma-separated list of JAR files that should be added to the YARN application's distributed cache. The distributed cache is a mechanism in YARN for distributing application-specific resources (like JAR files) to YARN containers on the worker nodes. The specified JAR files are made available to all containers in the YARN application, including the driver and executor containers.
>
> In summary, the main difference between these two properties is their scope:
>
> - `spark.yarn.secondary.jars` is specific to Spark and determines which additional JAR files are distributed alongside the primary application JAR to YARN worker nodes.
> - `spark.yarn.dist.jars` is a YARN property and determines which JAR files are added to the YARN application's distributed cache, making them available to all containers in the YARN application.
>
> Depending on your requirements, you might use one or both of these properties to ensure that all necessary dependencies are available to your Spark application when running on a YARN cluster.